# Understanding arrow function parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6

I just practiced a standard basic whiteboard problem: Create an array filled with integers from 0 through n. My solution worked but there were others posted that had very unusual syntax. I am really trying to understand it but the MDN docs aren't helping me very much. I can put together how `{length: n}` works but `(_, i) => i` seems strange. `_` is the unnamed function and it takes in `i` and returns `i`? but why is that there? I would love any help.

My solution:

```
function arr(n){
  var newArr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    newArr.push(i);
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

New syntax solution:

```
const arr = n => Array.from({length: n}, (_, i) => i);
```

Answer (score 5):

The first argument to the mapper function `Array.from` can accept indicates the current element being iterated over. That is, from an array-like collection of length `3`, for example, that argument will be `arrLike[0]`, or `arrLike[1]`, or `arrLike[2]`.

If there aren't any elements at that point in the collection, like here, then accessing those indicies will return `undefined`:

```js
const arr = n => Array.from({length: n}, (_, i) => {
  console.log(_);
  return i;
});

arr(3);
```

The underscore is just a variable name. You can define it however you want. It's a common convention for an *unused* argument to be called `_`, but it's only a convention, not a syntax rule.

Since the mapper function only cares about the current *index* being iterated over in order to construct the new array, it defines the second argument `i` and then returns it immediately. (`Array.from` can iterate over any object with a `length` property, from `0` to `length - 1`. Even if none of those properties actually exist on the object, the *index*, the second argument, will still be incremented from 0 up to `length - 1`.)